R: Cannot run console after update
im pretty new to programming and started getting into R using the pycharm IDE. Now i recently udpated Pycharm to the latest 2024 build and thought to do so for R as well. However, when i try to load my current R project i get the following error:
Cannot run console
No functional channel service provider found. Try adding a dependency on the grpc-okhttp, grpc-netty, or grpc-netty-shaded artifact
I have absolutely no clue what the issue is and how to resolve it. I am a complete noob, is there an eli5 explanation of whats wrong and how to fix this?
I tried reinstalling both Pycharm and R. I did a google and chatGPT search which told me to change my dependencies but i have no idea how to find or add dependencies for my project.

You aren't alone (unless that is you). Googling "grpc-okhttp" "pycharm" suggested https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-71847/R-Plugin-doesnt-work-after-updating-to-2024.1. (I don't use pycharm so I don't think I can help resolve it. Good luck!)

Not my post but that's exactly my problem. Alright so its the probably the plugin not updated yet. I guess I will just have to wait until its fixed. Thank you for the response tho, at least I'm not alone with this issue.

This happens with Pycharm updates. Compatibility of R plugin takes a few weeks to be restored. Just downgrade to the previous Pycharm version and wait it out.
